# Woocommerce - Edit Labels Backend

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to change the backend when you look at the order and it says "Customer Provided Note" i want to edit that to say something else but i can't find the hook anywhere online.

Comment: Please refer [link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-change-the-note-and-customer-provided-note-titles/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using this free plugin to change dynamically generated text within a WordPress plugin or theme. Although this plugin has the word translation in the title it is also used for changing dynamically generated text of the same language into different phrases or words too.

Loco Translate:  `https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/`

You can the search for text within WooCommerce and change it from the admin panel.

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you.